# How I can use React Native vector icons from different directory inside same component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, feather

`import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';`

`import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';`

**I want to use icons both from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather' and 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons' inside same component.**

But importing two *Icon* giving Syntax Error.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
     {/* message-circle is from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather' */}
      Icon name="message-circle" size={20} color='white' />
      {/* md-caret-down is from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons' */}
      {/* Icon name="message-circle" size={20} color='white' /> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import **react native vector icons** using (npm i react-native-vector-icons).

Then use the vector icons from different packages into your current component such as View, SafeAreaView , ScrollView ,....etc, as the code below.

You can use any package from vector icons like this method.

```
import {Ionicons,MaterialCommunityIcons,FontAwesome5} from '@expo/vector-icons';


    export default function App() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                  <Ionicons
                    name="information-circle"
                    size={24}
                    color={"#3280F0"}
                    />   
          {/* information-circle is from 'expo/vector-icons/Ionicons' */}
          </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
                     flex: 1,
                     backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.      `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save` is this command enough?

Comment: `npm link react-native-vector-icons` is this command also necessary during installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use modules imports of same name by aliasing as follows.

`import {Icon as FeatherIcon} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';`

`import {Icon as Ionicons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';`

For more reference you can refer this documentation on [medium.com](https://medium.com/dailyjs/using-import-aliases-in-javascript-a0b46237601c)

For as aliasing you have to use unique name. like

`import {Something as SomethingNewName} from .....`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use React Native vector icons from a different directory inside the same component like this:**

**Import names can't match, Just Change the import name:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {colors} from './src/global/styles';
import {SignInScreen} from './src/screens/authScreens/SignInScreen';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Visibility from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SignInScreen />
      <Icon name="lock" style={{color: colors.grey3}} size={16} />
      <Visibility
        name="visibility-off"
        style={{color: colors.grey3, marginRight: 10}}
        size={16}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```